# WPF Override xaml loading inside a usercontrol

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want ot create a UserControl that contains an element inside:

```
<local:MyUsercontrol>
   <TextBlock />
</local:MyUsercontrol>
```

But I want to load the XAML inside my usercontrol and create this TextBlock manually.
Is it possible?

Edit: TextBlock here is just for simplicity. Content could be very extensive inside, thats why I need t define it in XAML.

Comment: In the UserControl's code behind, set `Content = new TextBlock();`. Or have a top level named Grid, and write `grid.Children.Add(new TextBlock());`. This is very basic stuff, consider reading a WPF book first. You can't successfully use WPF without a basic understanding of how it works.

Comment: No, Clemens, I wouldn't ask if question was so simple. I don't want to create elements in code-behind, I want to define them in XAML specifically and then read xaml manually.

Comment: So what exactly stops you from declaring a more complex Content in XAML? And what is "read xaml manually" supposed to mean in concrete programming terms?

Comment: "Manually" means don't get control's content already created for me in contentcontrol. I need to see, that there is a textblock and create it in my way.

Comment: By searching something like **load wpf xaml dynamically** on the web, you will find many answers (for ex. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ashish/2007/08/14/dynamically-loading-xaml/)

Comment: You are either going to load a built in control or a custom user control. It is very basic. If you want to alter how a built in control works, you can create a template/style for it.